# JSONP is adding one getter into URL adress

Tags: ajax, jsonp

When im trying to get JSONP from one API, it adds `_=` and some random numbers. Example: from `api.google.com/get.php?data=45675` becomes `api.google.com/get.php?data=45675&_=1547482629641`

```
    var data = {
      resource_id: 'ca6e4d9e-776b-4608-8ad2-2f320c3c1ff2', // the resource id
      limit: 5, // get 5 results
      q: 'jones' // query for 'jones'
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://opendata.praha.eu/api/3/action/datastore_search',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('Total results found: ' + data.result.total)
      }
    });
```

This is error from console: `Couldn't load <script> from source „http://opendata.praha.eu/api/3/action/datastore_search?callback=jQuery3310043518013876097106_1547482629640&resource_id=ca6e4d9e-776b-4608-8ad2-2f320c3c1ff2&limit=5&q=jones&_=1547482629641“`

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: it is the anti caching param that jQuery is adding...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JSONP adds the _=timestamp to keep it from caching.

Add `cache : true` to the parameters to keep it from adding it.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks! :)